# Remove vertical line in tabular head

Tags: tables

I want to go from this:
[image: Image with line]

To: 
[image]

I have the following LaTeX:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}|c|c|c|c|c}
\textbf{Functionality} &
\rot{Old ICCS engine} &
\rot{Current ICCS engine} &
\rot{Confious system} &
\rot{OpenConf} &
\rot{START} \\

\hline

Customizable conference settings & & & & & \\

\end{tabular}
```

What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` to override the declared format specification for a cell:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}|c|c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Functionality}} &
\rot{Old ICCS engine} &
\rot{Current ICCS engine} &
\rot{Confious system} &
\rot{OpenConf} &
\rot{START} \\
\hline
Customizable conference settings & & & & & \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: @Tessmore you're welcome! I'm glad I could help.