# Add vertical line in tabular head when using multicol

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have the exact opposite problem described in this question : [Remove vertical line in tabular head](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102512/remove-vertical-line-in-tabular-head)

In my case, I am using this code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX|llll|llllllll@{}}
\toprule
 Title 1 & Title 2 & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Title 3} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Title 4} \\
         &         & N & R & F & I            &  N & R & F & I           \\
\midrule
Foo      & Bar     & f & o & o & o            &  b & a & r & r            \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the vertical line on the left of the 3rd column does not show in the header, which is exactly the expected behaviour when using `multicolumn` according to the question I linked.

What should I do for the vertical line to show in the heading line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `\multicolumn{4}{l|}{Title 3}` (note `l|`) so as to put a vertical line after `Title 3`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX|llll|llllllll@{}}
\toprule
 Title 1 & Title 2 & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Title 3} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Title 4} \\
         &         & N & R & F & I            &  N & R & F & I           \\
\midrule
Foo      & Bar     & f & o & o & o            &  b & a & r & r            \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But as the saying goes here in the site, vertical lines are evil and you should be using `booktabs` (See the gap in those vertical lines at horizontal line intersections..

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I had been away for a while so still picking up my speed. :) Thanks.